# Getting Type Mismatch Issue while Adding parameter to XSLT using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, xslt

I have got below code in VBScript:

```vb
<%

Option Explicit  

#importXSLT "tcm:228-190529-2048" As expandXSLT
#importXSLT "tcm:228-642694-2048" As renderXSLT

Dim xml, currentDateTime

Set xml = getNewDomDocument()
xml.loadXML TDSE.GetListPublications(3)

expandXSLT.input = xml
Call expandXSLT.addParameter("publication", Component.Publication.Id)
expandXSLT.transform

xml.loadXML(expandXSLT.output)
'WriteOut xml.xml

currentDateTime = now
renderXSLT.input = xml
Call renderXSLT.addParameter("currentPublishedDate", currentDateTime)
renderXSLT.transform

WriteOut renderXSLT.output

Set xml = Nothing

%>
```

You can see there is two syntax where I am adding the XSLT parameter, the first one is working fine i.e.

```vb
expandXSLT.input = xml
Call expandXSLT.addParameter("publication", Component.Publication.Id)
expandXSLT.transform
```

However the new requirement was that, we need to send current date time from here to the XSLT, so I have added the same logic to send the current date & time to my XSLT, below is code added by me

```vb
 currentDateTime = now
    renderXSLT.input = xml
    Call renderXSLT.addParameter("currentPublishedDate", currentDateTime)
    renderXSLT.transform
```

But when I am trying to run the above code its giving below error:

**Type mismatch.
 (source: Call renderXSLT.addParameter("publishedDate", currentDateTime)).**

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try whether converting the `currentDateTime` value you have to a string first to pass that string to XSLT e.g. `CStr(currentDateTime)`.